# (FFMPEG) avformat_write_header crashes (MSVC2013) (C++) (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, libavformat

I just downloaded FFMPEG and now I'm trying to use it in Qt with MSVC2013 compiler.

To understand how it works, I started reading the documentation and the API.
According to this [figure](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Stream-copy), I was trying to make a little test with libavformat.

I did all they said in the [demuxing module](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#details), then the muxing module. But, my program crashes when I call the avformat_write_header() function.

I would like to know what I did wrong and if you could help me to understand that.

In the main:

```
av_register_all();

if(!decode())
    return;
```

The decode() methode:

```
bool MainWindow::decode()
{
AVFormatContext *formatContext = NULL;
AVPacket packet;

/**************** muxing varaiables ******************/

AVFormatContext *muxingContext = avformat_alloc_context();
AVOutputFormat *outputFormat = NULL;
AVIOContext *contextIO = NULL;
AVCodec *codecEncode = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_WMAV2);
AVStream *avStream =  NULL;
AVCodecContext *codecContext = NULL;


/******************* demuxing **************************/

//open a media file
if(avformat_open_input(&formatContext,"h.mp3",NULL,NULL)!=0)
{
    qDebug() << "paka ouve fichier";
    return false;
}

//function which tries to read and decode a few frames to find missing          
information.
if(avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext,NULL)<0)
{
    qDebug()<<"paka find stream";
    return false;
}


/**************** muxing *************************/

//The oformat field must be set to select the muxer that will be used.
muxingContext->oformat = outputFormat;

//Unless the format is of the AVFMT_NOFILE type, the pb field must be set to
//an opened IO context, either returned from avio_open2() or a custom one.
if(avio_open2(&contextIO,"out.wma",AVIO_FLAG_WRITE,NULL,NULL)<0)
{
    qDebug() <<"paka kreye fichier soti";
    return false;
}
muxingContext->pb = contextIO;

//Unless the format is of the AVFMT_NOSTREAMS type, at least
//one stream must be created with the avformat_new_stream() function.
avStream = avformat_new_stream(muxingContext,codecEncode);

//The caller should fill the stream codec context information,
//such as the codec type, id and other parameters
//(e.g. width / height, the pixel or sample format, etc.) as known

codecContext = avStream->codec;
codecContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO;
codecContext->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_WMAV2;
codecContext->sample_fmt = codecEncode->sample_fmts[0];
codecContext->bit_rate = 128000;
codecContext->sample_rate = 44000;
codecContext->channels = 2;

//The stream timebase should be set to the timebase that the caller desires
//to use for this stream (note that the timebase actually used by the muxer
//can be different, as will be described later).

avStream->time_base = formatContext->streams[0]->time_base;
qDebug()<<formatContext->streams[0]->time_base.num <<"/" 
<<formatContext-    >streams[0]->time_base.den;


//When the muxing context is fully set up, the caller must call     
//avformat_write_header()
//to initialize the muxer internals and write the file header

qDebug() << "does not crash yet";
if(avformat_write_header(muxingContext,NULL) <0)
{
    qDebug()<<"cannot write header";
    return false;
}
qDebug() << "OOps you can't see me (John Cena)";

///////////////////// Reading from an opened file //////////////////////////
while(av_read_frame(formatContext,&packet)==0)
{
    //The data is then sent to the muxer by repeatedly calling
    //av_write_frame() or av_interleaved_write_frame()
    if(av_write_frame(muxingContext,&packet)<0)
        qDebug()<<"paka write frame";
    else
        qDebug()<<"writing";
}

//Once all the data has been written, the caller must call
//av_write_trailer() to flush any buffered packets and finalize
//the output file, then close the IO context (if any) and finally
//free the muxing context with avformat_free_context().

if(av_write_trailer(muxingContext)!=0)
{
    qDebug()<<"paka ekri trailer";
    return false;
}


return true;
}
```

The program shows the message *does not crash yet*. But not *OOps you can't see me (John Cena)*

And there is no error. I used an MP3 file as input and I would like to ouput it in WMA.

Comment: It's crashing in `libavformat/mux.c` line 295 because `muxingContext->oformat` is `NULL`.

Comment: There is a Qt ffmpeg wrapper - https://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/

Comment: How can I create an AVOutputFormat non NULL ?

Comment: Qt ffmpeg wrapper is only for video. Not audio

Comment: I don't know yet why using AVOutputFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of avformat_alloc_context(), use avformat_alloc_output_context2(). This will set muxingContext->oformat.

Comment: Hi, I used avformat_alloc_output_context2() before calling 
(muxingContext->oformat = outputFormat and without  muxingContext->oformat = outputFormat)  and avformat_write_header(). But it keeps crashing

Comment: Do you have a backtrace of your crash?

Comment: I just run the program in debug mode. I found a write access violation but, I cannot understand why. I did exactly what I read in the muxing api Detailed Description. Maybe it's because I don't understand well this word "Unless the format is of the AVFMT_NOFILE type". How can I know if a format is of the AVFMT_NOFILE type or AVFMT_NOSTREAMS  type. The exception comes from AVIOContext that I opened with avio_open2() before setting it to the muxingContext->pb like it says in the muxing api description.

Comment: I have some examples file. I will test them and understand them. I think it will be better

Comment: That's not a backtrace, Visual Studio calls it a call trace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio IDE, [when you debug in Qt it shows the call stack trace when the program is interrupted.](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-debug-mode.html#viewing-call-stack-trace). I could not show you the call stack trace because I could not copy to paste it.

level       function                           file                     line         
0 avformat_write_header avformat_56  0x62ff10e4 
1 _unlock                          mlock.c                368            0xffff754

Comment: next: 0 KiUserExceptionDispatcher ntdll  0x779d6fd2 
1 avformat_write_header avformat_56  0x62ff10e4 
2 _unlock mlock.c 368 0xffff754

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have resolved the problem. All I had to do is read the examples file.

Comment: @user3502626  can you please post the answer